# pandas select top N values for each multi index group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have the dataframe

```
data = {'fruit': ['pear','pear','pear','banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'cherry', 'pear','cherry','pear','banana', 'banana', 'banana','banana', 'cherry', 'cherry','banana', 'cherry', 'cherry', 'cherry', 'cherry'],
'country': ['france','france', 'france', 'albania', 'albania', 'albania','france', 'france','france','france', 'albania', 'albania','france','france', 'france', 'france','france', 'france', 'france', 'france', 'armenia'],
'id': ['01','01','01','01','01','01','02','02','03','03','011', '011', '011','011', '6', '6','6', '5', '5', '5','5'],
'month1': ['january','november','january','january','january','january','january', 'november','march','march', 'november', 'march', 'january','january', 'march', 'january','november', 'march', 'march', 'november','july'],
'month': ['january','november','january','january','january','january','january', 'november','march','march', 'november', 'march', 'january','january', 'march', 'january','november', 'march', 'march', 'november','july']        
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['fruit','country', 'id','month1', 'month'])
```

[image]

I make with `df.pivot_table(values='month', index=['fruit','country'], columns='month1', aggfunc='count').reset_index()` the pivot table, where i get for each multi index group (fruit and country)

[image]

I need to get for each group top 3 values, but it can be every N values.
Can anyone see the problem

Output dataframe

[image]

Comment: Do you need the output table in the format you show i.e. one line for months and one line for the count?

Comment: @not_speshal Yes. If i get another format how i can understand which month describes line for the count

Comment: See if this format works: `df.groupby(["fruit", "country", "month"]).count()["month1"]`

Comment: @not_speshal Yes it suits me. But how i can mention the specific top N? And sort by desc in each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you're able to work with this format:

```
N = 3 #for N largest
df = df.groupby(["fruit", "country", "month"]).count()["month1"].rename("count")
df = df.groupby(["fruit", "country"]).nlargest(N)
df.index = df.index.droplevel([0,1])
df = df.reset_index()
df
>>
     fruit  country     month  count
0   banana  albania   january       3
1   banana  albania     march       1
2   banana  albania  november       1
3   banana   france   january       2
4   banana   france  november       1
5   cherry  armenia      july       1
6   cherry   france     march       4
7   cherry   france   january       2
8   cherry   france  november       1
9     pear   france   january       2
10    pear   france  november       2
11    pear   france     march       1
```